# How to fix "TypeError: len() of unsized object"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am getting:

**TypeError: len() of unsized object**

after running the following script:

```
from numpy import *

v=array(input('Introduce un vector v: '))
u=array(input('Introduce un vector u: '))

nv= len(v)
nu= len(u)

diferenza= 0; i=0

if nv==nu:

    while i<nv:
        diferenza=diferenza + ((v[i+1]-u[i+1]))**2

    modulo= sqrt(diferenza)
    print('Distancia', v)
else:
    print('Vectores de diferente dimensión')
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 17):

Use the arrays' [`size`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) attribute instead:

```
nv = v.size
nu = u.size
```

---

You also probably want to use [`numpy.fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html#numpy.fromstring) to take and convert the input string into an array:

```
>>> v = np.fromstring(input('enter the elements of the vector separated by comma: '), dtype=int, sep=',')
enter the elements of the vector separated by comma: 1, 2, 3
>>> v
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> len(v)
3
>>> v.size
3
```

Comment: Given that he assumes vectors `len` and `size` are equivalent. But I downvoted because `numpy.array` do work with `len`, except if it's a scalar (which throws the mentioned error).

Comment: that actually makes a lot of sense! thanks for the explanation

Comment: @MSeifert So we do not need to assume `len` and `.size` are the same because infact they already are, since OP is working with a vector

Comment: @MSeifert It's no problem. Cheers

Comment: The `np.fromstring` is a good recommendation, so I removed the downvote.

Comment: Now, `np.frombuffer` is the way to go:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/__main__.py:3: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead
  app.launch_new_instance()

Comment: @fcpenha: That's specifically the *binary* mode of `fromstring` that's deprecated. This code is passing a nonempty `sep`, which triggers the non-deprecated mode. `frombuffer` doesn't handle that.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error occurred when I had the following situation:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1]])

arr_squeezed = arr.squeeze()
len(arr_squeezed)  # TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

For this to work properly, make sure that array you're squeezing contains more then one element.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to input two sets of values to two numpy arrays but it was not working.

```
import numpy as np
x=np.array(input('enter x values '))
y=np.array(input('enter y values '))
m=(len(x)*sum(x*y)-sum(x)*sum(y))/(len(x)*sum(x*x)-sum(x)**2)
c=(sum(y)-m*sum(x))/len(x)
print ('the required straight line is','y=',m,'x+ ',c)
```

This was the error that showed up. "TypeError: len() of unsized object"

Then I modified it by adding eval() function and everything is working fine.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(eval(input("enter x value: ")))
y = np.array(eval(input("enter y value: ")))
m = ( len(x)*sum(x*y)-sum(x)*sum(y))/(len(x)*sum(x**2)-sum(x)**2)
c = (sum(y)-m*sum(x))/len(x)

print("The required straightline is: y =",m,"x +",round(c,5))
```