# len() of unsized object ex. num_var= len(energy.iloc[1, :])

Tags: python

I keep getting "TypeError: len() of unsized object"
when trying to create a plot that uses index as x value and price as y value.

```
def tsplot2(y, title, lags=None, figsize=(12,8)):
if not isinstance(y, pd.Series):
    y = pd.Series(y)
    fig= plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    layout=(2,2)
    ts_ax=plt.subplot2grid(layout, (0,0))
    hist_ax=plt.subplot2grid(layout, (0,1))
    acf_ax=plt.subplot2grid(layout, (1,0))
    pacf_ax=plt.subplot2grid(layout, (1,1))

    y.plot(ax=ts_ax)
    ts_ax.set_title(title, fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
    y.plot(ax=hist_ax, kind='hist', bins=25)
    hist_ax.set_title('Histogram')
    smt.graphics.plot_acf(y, lags=lags, ax=acf_ax)
    smt.graphics.plot_pacf(y, lags=lags, ax=pacf_ax)
    sns.despine()
    plt.tight_layout()
    return ts_ax, acf_ax, pacf_ax


num_var= len(series.iloc[1,:])
for i in range(0, num_var):
    tsplot2(series.iloc[:,i].dropna() , title=series.columns[i], lags=48)
```

Comment: You can try using the `.size` attribute. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40142263/6685140

Comment: When I try that I get TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: Use `.size` only, not `len(....size)`

Comment: What is the output of  `series.iloc[1, :]` when you print it?

Comment: IndexingError: Too many indexers (I only have one index)

Comment: The .size fixed the first line. On the next line i still get IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: theodox: that also works.

Comment: You must not use `,` inside list slicing (`list[start:stop:step]`)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed code. I elminated 
"if not isinstance(y, pd.Series):
y = pd.Series(y)"
There is also no need to use a for loop when I can just plug series into the function.