# len() of unsized object (list)

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to modify the weights of cifar cnn and rerun inference with the modified weights. When I try to modify the weights by passing it to a function, I get the Len() of unsized object error.

```
f1 = h5py.File('/content/model_weights.h5', 'r+')     # open the file
data = np.array(f1.get('/conv1d_1/conv1d_1/bias:0'))
data[...] = one_hot_bit_List(data)                      # assign new values to data
f1.close()
```

This is the function that I pass the List to:

```
 def one_hot_bit_List(myList) :
   # m = np.fromstring(myList)
    for n in range(0, len(myList)) :
        myList[n] = one_hot_bit_val(myList[n])
    return myList
```

Error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-bec51affd860> in <module>()
      1 f1 = h5py.File('/content/model_weights.h5', 'r+')     # open the file
      2 data = np.array(f1.get('/conv1d_1/conv1d_1/bias:0'))
----> 3 data[...] = one_hot_bit_List(data)                      # assign new values to data
      4 f1.close()

<ipython-input-14-83e75db70b57> in one_hot_bit_List(myList)
     70 def one_hot_bit_List(myList) :
     71    # m = np.fromstring(myList)
---> 72     for n in range(0, len(myList)) :
     73         myList[n] = one_hot_bit_val(myList[n])
     74     return myList

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

I am new to python so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you include the error traceback in the question please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142166/how-to-fix-typeerror-len-of-unsized-object

Comment: Already tried this but I got another error afterwards regarding list size

Comment: I got "'list' object has no attribute 'size'" when I tried your link

Comment: That makes no sense. The original error is because `myList` is a numpy array, not a list. How can it then complain that it's a list?

Answer (score 2):

A better way to iterate through lists in a `for` loop is to do the following:

```
for item in mylist:
    print(item)
```

This will print each item in the list, by assigning the value of each entry to the variable defined in the `for` statement as it iterates.

You could do the following:

```
def one_hot_bit(list):
    one_hot_bit_list = []
    for item in list:
        one_hot_bit_list.append(one_hot_bit_val(item))
    return one_hot_bit_list
```

Comment: I upvoted but it didn't solve the main issue. Thanks though

Answer (score 2):

If I make an array from a dictionary, I get your error:

```
In [107]: data = np.array({})                                                   
In [108]: data                                                                  
Out[108]: array({}, dtype=object)
In [109]: len(data)                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-c6201f8cef64> in <module>
----> 1 len(data)

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

That suggests that in:

```
data = np.array(f1.get('/conv1d_1/conv1d_1/bias:0'))
```

`f1.get(...)` is a `h5py.group` rather than a `dataset`.  A `group` is dictionary-like.

If `f1.get(...)` returned a dataset, `data = f1.get(...)[:]` would be a better way of fetching the data.  And it would raise an error is that file element was a group.

You need to review the structure of that `h5py` file, and access elements, group and/or datasets correctly.

Comment: This is helpful! I will read more about it